# Adding a reason to a command

Tags: discord.py

With this I'm wanting to have the reason work, I would like it similar to the *ban command where you have a reason, but instead of it logging in audit logs the reason you give replaces {reason} in the embed. It doesn't throw up any error codes when I try it out but it doesn't send the embed to my dm's.

```html
#Command to send a user their denied outcome
@bot.command()
async def deny(ctx, *, user : discord.User, reason):
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(f'✅')
    embed = Embed(title="Application Denied",
                  description=f"Hello {user.name}, your application is being denied due to {reason}. Feel free to re-apply in 2 weeks, we wish you luck!",
                  color=0xffffff,
                  timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/935059565588930601/946167642207686686/rejected-stamp.gif")
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Denied By {ctx.author.name} | {ctx.guild.name}', icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/935059565588930601/945768014958178324/ezgif-1-5c3f7a6a54.gif?width=778&height=778")
    
    await user.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
@bot.command()
async def deny(ctx, user : discord.User,*,reason = "No reason was provided"):
    reason = "".join(reason)
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Application Denied",
                  description=f"Hello {user.name}, your application is being denied due to {reason}. Feel free to re-apply in 2 weeks, we wish you luck!",
                  color=0xffffff,
                  timestamp=datetime.utcnow())
    embed.set_image(url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/935059565588930601/946167642207686686/rejected-stamp.gif")
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Denied By {ctx.author.name} | {ctx.guild.name}', icon_url="https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/935059565588930601/945768014958178324/ezgif-1-5c3f7a6a54.gif?width=778&height=778")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(f'✅')
    await user.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I've got a question, what does the actual .join(reason) do and how does this work? I was so confused and cannot find it anywhere for when I look for what it means.